# Kotlin sealed interface serialization

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, kotlin-multiplatform

Kotlin sealed interface serialization seems to be broken, unless using an explicitly registered serialization module. Am I missing something?

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlin.test.Test

sealed interface iFoo {
    @Serializable
    @SerialName("a")
    class A() : iFoo//Foo(),
}

class EventTest {
    @Test
    fun testKotlinLang() {
//        // this works
//        val json = Json { serializersModule = SerializersModule {
//                polymorphic(iFoo::class) {
//                    subclass(iFoo.A::class, iFoo.A.serializer())
//                } } }

        val json = Json

        val a = iFoo.A() as iFoo
        val s = json.encodeToString(a)
        val a1: iFoo = json.decodeFromString(s)
    }
}
```

```
Class 'A' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'iFoo'.
Mark the base class as 'sealed' or register the serializer explicitly.
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Class 'A' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'iFoo'.
Mark the base class as 'sealed' or register the serializer explicitly.
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractPolymorphicSerializerKt.throwSubtypeNotRegistered(AbstractPolymorphicSerializer.kt:102)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractPolymorphicSerializerKt.throwSubtypeNotRegistered(AbstractPolymorphicSerializer.kt:113)
    at kotlinx.serialization.PolymorphicSerializerKt.findPolymorphicSerializer(PolymorphicSerializer.kt:109)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonEncoder.encodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonEncoder.kt:224)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.Json.encodeToString(Json.kt:85)
    at io.almer.EventTest.testKotlinLang(EventTest.kt:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at 
..............
```

Note that I am using the multiplatform mode but the JVM run fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's not implemented yet :(

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1417

Answer (score 0):

Possible work-around using `sealed interface` with `@JvmInline`: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1417#issuecomment-844300565